# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, replicação

Olá, estou com o seguinte erro:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "new" CONTEXT:  Error
>   occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute
>   command.
>
> SQL statement "select             dblink_exec(            'host=***.***.**.**
>   port=5432 dbname=** user = ** password = ***' , 'INSERT INTO
>   teste.teste_replica ("id", "nome")            values (new.id, new.nome)')"
>   PL/pgSQL function teste_bd() line 26 at SQL statement}

e essa é a minha linha de código que está com o erro:

```
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            select 
            dblink_exec( 
            'dbname=postgres 
            hostaddr=***.**.**.***
            user=*** 
            password=*** 
            port=5432',
            '--INSERT INTO teste.teste_replica SELECT NEW.*;
            INSERT INTO teste.teste_replica ("id", "nome") 
            values (NEW."id",NEW."nome")');
            RETURN NEW;
```

Lembrando que ambos são bancos testes, onde eu preciso replica o dados após insert, update e delete do servidor A para o servidor B, mas esse erro está me impedindo, sabe como posso arrumar?

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            select 
            dblink_exec( 
            'dbname=postgres 
            hostaddr=***.**.**.***
            user=*** 
            password=*** 
            port=5432',
            concat('INSERT INTO teste.teste_replica ("id", "nome") values (', NEW."id", ',', quote_literal(NEW."nome"), ')');
            RETURN NEW;
```

Comment: valeu deu certo porem agora o delete ta dando erro, sendo que estava ok